# for loop django template logic - how can I do this?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to output 2 items for each row. I have 4 items coming from db.

```
<table>
 <tr>
{% for item in items %}
   <td>
  {{item.name}},{{item.size}}
   </td>
{% endfor %}
 </tr>
</table>
```

this is giving me

```
name1, 23m^2 | name2,20m^2 | name3,15m^2 | name4,10m^2
```

but i need

```
name1, 23m^2 | name2,20m^2
name3,15m^2 | name4,10m^2
```

each row being contained in separate `<tr>`. I am stuck how to break the loop and assign new row..

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich, no, not more.. well may be more, but it will be fix number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch the `<tr>` and `forloop`, and also use [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)

Something like this:

```
{% if items %}
<tr>
{% for item in items %}
     <td>{{item.name}},{{item.size}}</td>
     {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
     </tr>
     <tr>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: awesome as usual! :). let me test

Comment: but i get the idea, i can check the loopcounter and generate <tr> right?

Comment: Simple answer: YES you can (and you should, ideally) but in this case, the logic is not so straightforward. Check the edit and let me know if that serves the purpose

Comment: yes, working now, i just had to generate <tr> after <td>. now working like anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close `<td>` tag.

```
<table>
 <tr>
{% for item in items %}
   <td>
  {{item.name}},{{item.size}}
   </td> <!-- here -->
{% endfor %}
 </tr>
</table>
```